# Download files from url of site directory

Tags: php, linux, wget

Two zip files and Two images are in https://example.com/directory. (Since index.php file is available in this directory we don't know the file names of those files).

Is there any possible way to find names of above four files using PHP or Linux commands?

Comment: Usually the path in unix will be under /var/www/html/<directory to view>

Comment: @FreedomPride We need to do in from outside of the site. For en example, if we need to get the content of a page we use `file_get_contents()` php functions. Like wise I am looking a way to find the names of those files

Comment: Is the server yours? does the website trying to access from the "outside" live in the same server as the one that host the files you are trying to get?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to look "beyond the veil" into someone else's website directory. Are you actually asking for help to hack/crack a website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must keep in mind: if your web-server disallows to scan a directory then you couldn't get file names. But if the directory is shared in web-server you can get a list of files with using `wget` command. For example:

```
wget -nv -r -np '*.*' https://example.com/directory/
```

Comment: it's download all files in the directory, but download something else too, some files like `index.html?C=D;O=D` which I don't have in my directory. can you tell me what is it?

Comment: @mahradbt see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66974403/383904

Answer (score 1):

Say you have on your webserver `example.com` a directory like: `/multimedia/` and you want to retrieve its contents like *mp3, jpg, png*, etc - but **not the listing index** nor *tmp* index files like i.e: `index.html•C=D;O=D`:

```
wget -r -R "*.html*" -np -nd -l 1 example.com/multimedia/
```

where:

```sh
-r             # Recursive
-R "*.html*"   # Reject tmp and listing html files
-np            # Don't ascend to the parent directory
-nd            # Don't create parent directories
-l 1           # Only one level deep (multimedia/ folder only)
```

To learn more: run `man wget` or `wget --help` or visit [gnu.org WGET](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$files=[];    
$folder="/directory/directory/directory/";
if (is_dir($folder)){                       // check whether exists or not
    $allfiles = glob($folder.'/*.*');       // Read all filenames of $folder directory
    foreach($allfiles as $imgFile) {
        $files[]=$imgFile;              // Putting the names of $folder directory to array one by one
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($files);                          // printing the file name array to list aal names
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21589025)

Comment: Yes, definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understant HTTP protocals at all. According to HTTP protocal it doesn't know about any directory/sub-directory. You can't do things as such in HTTP Protocal.

You want to download  http://example.com/directory some files for which you don't know the names. For that you can't use PHP as such. You have to depend on external library such as wget etc. or FTP protocal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$dir = 'directory';
$filesArr = scandir($dir);

$files = array();
for($i=2; $i<count($filesArr);++$i){
if($filesArr[$i]=="index.php"){ continue; }
$files[] = $filesArr[$i];


}

$zipname = 'file1.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
  $zip->addFile($dir.'/'.$file,   $dir.'/'.$file);
}


header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
$zip->close();
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I am using below sample in my project and its working fine for me,

```
<?php
$directory='directory';
$handler= opendir("$directory"."/");
$i=0;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handler))) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file !='..'){
            echo $file.'<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use PHPs `scandir` Method.
Try this:

```
<?php
    $files = scandir('./');
    print_r($files);
```

This should print all files in the current directory. More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)